# Accessing a resource via codebehind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, code-behind

I have a custom collection defined in my window resources as follows (in a Sketchflow app so the window is actually a UserControl):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ds:MyCollection x:Key="myKey" x:Name="myName" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I want to be able to refer to this collection in the codebehind, which I expected would be by the x:Name, but I can't seem to access it.

I can get a reference to it using

```
myRef = (MyCollection) this.FindName("myKey");
```

but this seems hackish. Is this bad practice, and what would be better? Thanks :)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You should use `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`'s `FindResource()` or `TryFindResource()` methods.

Also, a good practice is to create a string constant which maps the name of your key in the resource dictionary (so that you can change it at only one place).

Comment: You can use: Application.Current.FindResource(errorColorResourceName) as  MyCollection or this.FindResource("RainbowBrush") as MyCollection. It depends on the context.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Also, a good practice is to create a string constant which maps the name of your key in the resource dictionary (so that you can change it at only one place)." ?  Where would such a string constant go that would change the XAML key as well as the C# code behind?

Comment: +1 for > Can you elaborate on "Also, a good practice is to create a string constant which maps the name of your key in the resource dictionary (so that you can change it at only one place)." ? Where would such a string constant go that would change the XAML key as well as the C# code behind?

Comment: @MikeChristiansen [AdonisUI](https://github.com/benruehl/adonis-ui) is a good exemple of that, if you look in `src/AdonisUI/Brushes.cs` you have a bunch of keys that are used in the templates, for example in [Buttons.cs](https://github.com/benruehl/adonis-ui/blob/master/src/AdonisUI.ClassicTheme/DefaultStyles/Button.xaml) where you have a `{DynamicResource {x:Static adonisUi:Brushes.ForegroundBrush}}`.

Answer (score 31):

You may also use `this.Resources["mykey"]`.  I guess that is not much better than your own suggestion.

Comment: This is for Windows 8 Store Apps.

Comment: @cederlof, you can use this with WPF too.

Comment: This will not work if the resource is in another file, for instance a theme color.  FindResource is the way to go.

Answer (score 23):

Not exactly direct answer, but strongly related:

In case the resources are in a different file - for example ResourceDictionary.xaml

You can simply add `x:Class` to it:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Namespace.NewClassName"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <ds:MyCollection x:Key="myKey" x:Name="myName" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then use it in code behind:

```
var res = new Namespace.NewClassName();
var col = res["myKey"];
```

Comment: +1, but to be able to find resources using it's key I had to call `res.InitializeComponent()` before attempting to access the key otherwise the object would show no keys and the call to `res["myKey"]` would return null.

Comment: Wow that's awesome... I never knew you could do that and it just solved a problem for me quick and easy!  I did need to call InitializeComponent() like @StephenRoss said but other than that works like a charm.

Comment: A perfect solution to use from `Converters`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to access a resource from some other class (i.g. not a xaml codebehind), you can use

```
Application.Current.Resources["resourceName"];
```

from `System.Windows` namespace.

Comment: This is useful if you need to access the resource from a static constructor or method, and therefore don't have the ability to call `FindResource` or `TryFindResource`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a resource key like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static local:Foo.MyKey}">Blue</SolidColorBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="{StaticResource {x:Static local:Foo.MyKey}}" />
```

```
public partial class Foo : UserControl
{
    public Foo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var brush = (SolidColorBrush)FindResource(MyKey);
    }

    public static ResourceKey MyKey { get; } = CreateResourceKey();

    private static ComponentResourceKey CreateResourceKey([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
        return new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(Foo), caller); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this depends on the type of key. E.g. a key in a `DataTemplate` is of type `DataTemplateKey`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the resources on C# (Desktop WPF W/ .NET Framework 4.8) using the code below

```
{DefaultNamespace}.Properties.Resources.{ResourceName}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice clean example from Microsoft documents makes it simple:

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button button = (Button)sender;
  button.Background = (Brush)this.FindResource("RainbowBrush");
}
```

Comment: This has already been answered.