# BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" in Code Behind for Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, basedon

How can you set the following in code behind?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
```

I'm using a Theme merged in App.xaml. It works great for all Controls but when I define a Style for something, e.g. `TextBox`,  the Theme Style doesn't get picked up unless I use `BasedOn` like above, instead it gets the default `TextBox` Style.

Now I'm creating a `DataGridTextColumn` in code behind and I can't get the `BasedOn` part to work for the `EditingElementStyle`

```
Style editingStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
editingStyle.BasedOn = ...?;
```

Any suggestions? Also, is there any way to get the Theme Style instead of the default Style applied without using BasedOn?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to get the Theme applied to a given control and have the local style override the Theme components which it affects?

Comment: @Aaron: I'm using a Theme which affects all controls. But in many places I need to add specific setters, triggers etc. Binding `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` in the `ListBox` ItemContainerStyle for example. I want the Theme Style applied with an additional setter

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
editingStyle.BasedOn = (Style) FindResource(typeof (TextBox))
```

And I don't know any way how you can make it apply the Theme style without specifying `BasedOn`. If there is such a way, I would like to know it too...

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
Style baseStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
Style editingStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
editingStyle.BasedOn = baseStyle;
```

You can also do it in the constructor:

```
Style editingStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox), baseStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I hoped that would work to but the Theme Style isn't picked up for some reason. If I do it in Xaml it works..

Answer (score 2):

I like the [answer of Pavlo Glazkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195391/3621055), but it does not compile.

FindResource is [(non-static) member of FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx).
It is required to identify the context of the search request.

So I recommend this:

```
style.BasedOn = (Style)frameworkElement.FindResource(typeof(TextBox));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that occurred a few years after this question and provides a functional way to reference theme from XAML.
Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/24286059/5104896

**First** - Define the XAML resource dictionary with an `x:class` identifier along with an `x:Key` of your resource

`ResourceDictionary x:Class="YourNameSpaceHere.DataGridCellTemplates"`

```
<Style x:Key="ValidationError_TextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTempate}" />
</Style>
```

**Second** - Create a `.cs` file that will initialize the resource class.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace YourNameSpaceHere
{
    public partial class DataGridCellTemplates : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public DataGridCellTemplates()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Lastly** - Reference from you code

```
using YourNameSpaceHere;
....
var res = new DataGridCellTemplates();
Style test = res["ValidationError_TextBox"] as Style;
```