# WPF - Set Style of TextBox programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On my `XAML` i have defined a special style. Here i can access these with my defined resource like:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TransparentInput}" Text="Hello World!" [...] />
```

But how i can set the `Style` of an component **programatically**?

I wan't to add components programatically like

```
TextBox test = new TextBox();
test.Text = "Hello World!";
test.Style = [???] //<--- How i set here the static resource "TransparentInput"?
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117886/accessing-a-resource-via-codebehind-in-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
test.Style = TryFindResource("TransparentInput") as Style;
```

Comment: Another "ugly" method: `test.Style = (Style) this.Resources["TransparentInput"];`

Comment: The main benefit of using TryFindResource is that it simply returns null if the style cannot be found in the current scope.